# Difference between overriding a class and declaring everything in controller?

Tags: ios, storyboard, overriding, iboutlet

everyone. I have two possibilities to code:

I have a mapView, that needs to have some variables. I wonder what is the best way to do it ?

First:

```
class UGOMapView: MKMapView, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    let regionRadius: CLLocationDistance = 1000 
    var usrLocation: CLLocationManager!
    var annotationView: MKAnnotationView!


    func initUserLocation() {
        if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()) {
            usrLocation = CLLocationManager()
            usrLocation.delegate = self
            usrLocation.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            usrLocation.requestLocation()
        }
    }
}
```

Then in my storyboard:

[image]

and in my controller :     `@IBOutlet weak var mapView: UGOMapView!`

Or :

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    let regionRadius: CLLocationDistance = 1000 
    var usrLocation: CLLocationManager!
    var annotationView: MKAnnotationView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()) {
            usrLocation = CLLocationManager()
            usrLocation.delegate = self
            usrLocation.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            usrLocation.requestLocation()
        }
    }
```

Then in my storyboard:

[image]

(I have more than one function in my mapView. I don't know if the functions there is matter for one way or another?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your first approach is good**. It is because, it gives you **code separation and single point of modification**. If you create separate class for your map view, and suppose any issue comes related to map, **you will be pretty sure that the lines of code causing issue will be in this class**. Also if you want to handle map related actions , you can handle them here. One more benefit is that **you can use same class for multiple map views**. In case of view controller, you can't use the same code for other map view.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Does that apply everytime? Or is there contexts where the second way to code is the best ?

Comment: You can go for second way when you don't have lots of coding on map and you are going to use map view on single view controller. In this case its not wrong to use second approach as you will be sure where you have used map view and you can debug easily.hope it clears your doubts.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference of between **First approach** and **Second approach** is **Code Reuseablilty**.

First approach is always better idea because whenever you need to modify or change anything with that class you can directly redirect to that class.

Where in second approach it become unmanageable when you need to add some changes which makes you confusing.

Read this throughly :
https://www.objc.io/issues/13-architecture/subclassing/

You will get better idea when to subclass and when not.

Comment: So in any case, first approach will always be the best way to do it ? No contexts matter ?